# How propagate modification of HKLM to gpedit?

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy

I would to modify (enable and set value) of a Machine Group Policy with PowerShell. I understood this kind of Policy is based on Registry. That's why I tried to add my value with `Set-ItemProperty`command.

The new value is correctly set in registry but gpedit doesn't see it.
I tried to use GroupPolicy commands but I don't see how address the Local Group Policy because I don't reach to get a correct GUID.

The key I want to chang is this one: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run`

I think I miss something but I don't know what. An Idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are looking for can be found at https://superuser.com/questions/1192405/why-gpedit-and-the-corresponding-registry-entries-are-not-synchronized

> **Quoted from Wes**

Since the changes you make in the group policy editor affect what you see in the registry, it's perfectly logical to assume that the reverse is also true. However, it doesn't work that way.

Local group policy settings (which is what I believe you are referring to in your post) are stored in registry.pol files located in C:\Windows\system32\GroupPolicy. These files overwrite the corresponding keys in the registry every time the system performs a group policy refresh. The editor never actually reads the registry to see what settings it contains.

A group policy refresh is triggered whenever one of the following events occurs:

- At a regularly scheduled refresh interval (every 90 minutes by default)
- A user logon or logoff event (user policy only)
- A computer reboot (computer policy only)
- A manually triggered refresh via gpupdate
- A policy refresh command issued by an admin from the domain controller (if the computer is domain-joined).

It's important to remember that if the computer is domain-joined, domain policies will be applied after the local group policy files are processed (meaning that some settings may get overwritten by domain policy). You will not be able to see domain policies in the local group policy editor.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer lighted something. My primary need was not to modify the registry but to start an application when a user logon. After all I read, I think I will have even more issues with "Not Configured" LGP.  Maybe, you have an answer for another question : Do you think, I could do something similar with the GPMC module of Powershell ?

Comment: If all you are wanting to do is start an application upon login, I would suggest `Run` in `HKLM` or inside `NTUSER.DAT` for a particular user(`HKCU`, if logged in.) `\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` is the path. You can also use the `Startup` folder, user one or public one. You could also do a task in `Task Scheduler`

Comment: I was not aware about this registry path: `\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. It looks like one I want to modify but in a more global context. You gave me a new track to explore and I found this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/ee851671(v=msdn.10)) describing all registry path for startup application. Since my question, I implemented a solution with the startup folder, maybe, I will let me attempt by use of the new registry path